# I want to conditionally sort a table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sorting, sql-order-by

My problem at hand here is that I have a table which has data which is already sorted based on some rules(discussed further) I have to write a query which implements further sorting.

Sample table:

```
PBaseIDOrder    SecuritySymbol  TradeDate                 TransactionCode  rownum
1               13033w7l1       2017-01-06 00:00:00.000         li            76
1               13033w7l1       2017-01-06 00:00:00.000         pa            77
1               13033w7l1       2017-01-06 00:00:00.000         li            78
1               13033w7l1       2017-01-06 00:00:00.000         pa            79
1               13033w7l1       2017-01-06 00:00:00.000         li            80
1               13033w7l1       2017-01-06 00:00:00.000         pa            81
1               13033w7l1       2017-06-01 00:00:00.000         in            82
1               542433ry5       2017-01-06 00:00:00.000         pa           329
1               542433ry5       2017-01-06 00:00:00.000         li           330
1               542433ry5       2017-01-11 00:00:00.000         sl           331
1               542433ry5       2017-01-11 00:00:00.000         sa           332
```

Output that I want from query:
    Sample table:

```
PBaseIDOrder    SecuritySymbol  TradeDate                 TransactionCode  rownum
1               13033w7l1       2017-01-06 00:00:00.000         li            76
1               13033w7l1       2017-01-06 00:00:00.000         pa            77
1               13033w7l1       2017-01-06 00:00:00.000         li            78
1               13033w7l1       2017-01-06 00:00:00.000         pa            79
1               13033w7l1       2017-01-06 00:00:00.000         li            80
1               13033w7l1       2017-01-06 00:00:00.000         pa            81
1               13033w7l1       2017-06-01 00:00:00.000         in            82
1               542433ry5       2017-01-06 00:00:00.000         li           330
1               542433ry5       2017-01-06 00:00:00.000         pa           329
1               542433ry5       2017-01-11 00:00:00.000         sl           331
1               542433ry5       2017-01-11 00:00:00.000         sa           332
```

So the idea here is I want all the records sorted based on PBaseIDOrder then securitysymbol then TradeDate and then based upon transaction code. The sorting based on transaction code should be such that 'li' transaction code always comes before 'pa' and 'sl' transactioncode comes before 'sa' and after that 'in' should appear.

For example 
Suppose for securitysymbol '13033w7l1' there are 3 'li' 3 'pa' transactions then in this case which 'pa' will come after an 'li' is decided based on rownum value.

When I run this query all 'pi' and 'li' transaction appear grouped which I do not want.

```
select PortfolioBaseIDOrder,SecuritySymbol,TradeDate,TransactionCode,rownum 
from dbo.abc where SecuritySymbol='542433ry5' or SecuritySymbol='13033w7l1'
order by PortfolioBaseIDOrder,SecuritySymbol,TradeDate,( case TransactionCode 
                                                                when 'li' then 1 
                                                                when 'pa' then 2
                                                                when 'sl' then 3
                                                                when 'sa' then 4 end),rownum;
```

Comment: you cold highten the chance of an answer if you prepare a http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6  containing the dml and whatever select you did and edit your question, adding the link to this fiddle

Comment: Your query would seem to generate your expected output.  What is your actual output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following comes close to what you want:

```
order by PortfolioBaseIDOrder, SecuritySymbol, TradeDate,
         row_number() over (partition by PortfolioBaseIDOrder, SecuritySymbol, TradeDate, TransactionCode order by rownum),
         charindex(TransactionCode, 'li,pa,sl,sa')
```

It doesn't handle `in`, but that can be done separately:

```
order by PortfolioBaseIDOrder, SecuritySymbol, TradeDate,
         (case when TransactionCode = 'in' then 2 else 1 end),
         row_number() over (partition by PortfolioBaseIDOrder, SecuritySymbol, TradeDate, TransactionCode order by rownum),
         charindex(TransactionCode, 'li,pa,sl,sa')
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, you saved my day. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your ordering requirement by simply switching the positions of `case` and `rownum` in your order by clause.  So, the following query will get you the desired results.

I have used the table `StackOverflowTable2` as the name of the table. You can substitute it by your table name.

```
SELECT
     PBaseIDOrder
    ,SecuritySymbol
    ,TradeDate
    ,TransactionCode
    ,rownum
FROM dbo.StackOverflowTable2 sot
WHERE SecuritySymbol = '542433ry5'
OR SecuritySymbol = '13033w7l1'
ORDER BY PBaseIDOrder, SecuritySymbol, TradeDate, rownum, (CASE TransactionCode
    WHEN 'li' THEN 1
    WHEN 'pa' THEN 2
    WHEN 'sl' THEN 3
    WHEN 'sa' THEN 4
END);
```

When I ran the above query in SSMS, it gave the following results.

[image: SSMS results of above query]